# I want to know how I can check the color of my imageview on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imageview

This is what I have now, but it's wrong everytime

```
if(ivBall.equals(Color.RED))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is ivBall..? a color? an object? More info!

Comment: that's my imageview

Comment: this how i set the color: ivBall.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

Answer (score 0):

Set color to ImageView:

```
ivBall.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Try using this:

```
    ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable) ivBall.getBackground();
    if(drawable.getColor() == Color.RED)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Try `drawable.getColor() == Color.RED`

Comment: When i click the imageview the app will close

Comment: I set the color with: ivBall.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

Comment: contoling with: ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable) ivBall.getBackground();
            if(drawable.getColor() == Color.RED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: add `ivBall.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`